# Difference in Months between two dates in React.js using KeyboardDatePicker

Tags: html, reactjs, datepicker

```
const Index = (props) => {

    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(
        new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54")
      );
    
      const handleDateChange = (date) => {
        setSelectedDate(date);
      };
return (
<div>
//first date picker
 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider
                    utils={DateFnsUtils}
                    //  className={classes.formControlNew}

                    style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  >
                    <KeyboardDatePicker
                      style={{ marginLeft: "5%", width: "91%" }}
                      margin="normal"
                      id="date-picker-dialog1"
                      label="Start Date"
                      format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                      value={selectedDate}
                      onChange={handleDateChange}
                      KeyboardButtonProps={{
                        "aria-label": "change date",
                      }}
                    />
                  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>

// second date picker

 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider
                    utils={DateFnsUtils}
                    
                    style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  >
                    <KeyboardDatePicker
                      style={{ marginLeft: "5%", width: "91%" }}
                      margin="normal"
                      id="date-picker-dialog2"
                      label="End Date"
                      format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                      value={selectedDate}
                      onChange={handleDateChange}
                      KeyboardButtonProps={{
                        "aria-label": "change date",
                      }}
                    />
                  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
</div>
);
};
```

There are two date pickers using which I am taking two dates from user .In which first date is start date & second is End Date . I want to calculate difference between these two dates in months.How should i get the difference in months ? What are the calculations need to be done in Reactjs .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things missing here.

1. You are going to want to duplicate `selectedDate` and `handleDateChange` so that you can keep track of the two dates separately. Perhaps `selectedStartDate` and `selectedEndDate`
2. To calculate the difference, I would recommend using the `moment` npm package with syntax similar to:

`const months = moment.duration(moment(selectedEndDate).diff(moment(selectedStartDate))).asMinutes()`